# How can I draw a graph that looks like this?

Tags: graphs

I'm a new LaTeX user and I need to draw a graph that looks like this at short notice. I have no idea where to start, please can someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: [Ti*k*Z](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 \draw[-stealth] (-5,0) -- (8,0) node[below left]{$\omega$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[below left]{$D$};
 \draw[dashed] (-5,-2) -- (8,-2) node[midway,above]{$m$};
 \draw (-3.5,-2) --++ (5.5,5.5)node[above right] {$A$} 
    to[out=-60,in=180] node[pos=0.1,bullet,label=below left:$A_1$](A1){}
    node[pos=0.2,bullet,label=below left:$A_2$](A2){}   ++ (5.5,-5.5);
 \draw[<->] (3.4,0|-A1)--(3.4,0|-A2);
 \draw (-4.5,-2) --++ (5.5,5.5) node[above right] {$B$} 
 to[out=-60,in=180] node[pos=0.7,bullet,label=below left:$B_1$](B1){}
    node[pos=0.8,bullet,label=below left:$B_2$](B2){} ++ (5.5,-5.5);
 \draw[<->] (3.2,0|-B1)--(3.2,0|-B2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course your answer is perfect, but if the dashed line actually represents an aymptote and looking at the OP graph, I would extend the two lines to indicate "A function can cut an asymptote".

Comment: @manooooh In that case one needs to move the dashed line down by a tiny bit and use, say,  `in=179` instead of `in=180`.